# Fragment layout orientation management

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have small issue with fragment orientation changes, I have a DrawerActivity starting loading ProfileFragment inside, In left navigation bar Review button if clicks button loading ReviewFrament in same container. Now in ReviewFragement if change orientation its showing ProfileFrament(back page), its refreshing total page.

How to avoid misbehaviour from app?

Comment: please share your DrawerActivity Code and Layout code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked with placing flag for checking status of fragment based on that loading view.

Tried with config changes in manifest but its not changing layout view(if we want to change design as per orientation).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your `DrawerActivity` in `manifest` file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

So your activity tag will look like this.

```
<activity
    android:name="packagename.DrawerActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: But i have load different design layout if changes the orientation of screen.

Comment: ohh... then probably you should use `onConfigurationChanged();` in you `DrawerActivity` and do some logic in that.

Answer (score 0):

its happening because your activity is recreating after rotation so the fragment gets destroyed.

I would suggest the best to handle such situation is to use activity as a parent to fragment,  just as a container and put any layout in the activity and perform all other actions with fragments.

for example in your situation, Main activity should only contain the container like this

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and then for profile use `ProfileFragment` which will be launched from onCreate of your activity, something like this

```
// this will prevent the fragments from recreating on rotate
if (savedInstanceState == null){
        setSplashFragment();
        } else {
            //Do Nothing
        }
```

and in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ParentActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and use interface to tell activity to launch `ReviewFragement` on button clicks and so on.

This all might sound complicated and you might be looking for a quick solution but this the best approach you can use to avoid future conflicts.